# What is (*>*) in Isabelle?

Tags: symbols, isabelle

I have downloaded several `.thy` files in Isabelle that use `(*<*)` and `(*>*)`.They seem to have no effect as far as I can tell, but they must have a purpose. Does anyone know what they are used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special comments `(*<*)` and `(*>*)` tell the document preparation system of Isabelle to not include the enclosed theory text in the generated PDF documents. They are the predecessors of the more structured tags like `%invisible`, which also control what appears in the generated documents. For example,

```
lemma %invisible silly: "0 = 0" by simp
```

and

```
(*<*)
lemma silly: "0 = 0" by simp
(*>*)
```

have roughly the same effect, namely the whole lemma and its proof will not show up in the document. However, tags can only be attached to top-level commands like `definition`, `lemma`, `proof`, `by`. Hence, you cannot hide just parts of a command like in

```
 by(simp add: take_map(*<*) drop_map(*>*))
```

which will yield `by(simp add: take_map)` in the PDF, i.e., the `drop_map` is omitted.